# Compare dates in mysql when one date is posted from another page

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have been trying to compare two dates in a query, the code goes like this

```
WHERE   Reservation.InDate >= ".$_POST['dateSince']."
AND     (Reservation.ResStatus = 'Occupied' OR Reservation.ResStatus = 'Vacant')";
```

The query is working fine but it does not take the date condition into consideration, I have tried casting the two dates, I tried swapping the conditions, I tried other approaches but it seems that I am doing something wrong with the dates.

I have echoed $_POST['dateSince'] and the page does echo the date selected indeed.
I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: What is the value of `$_POST['dateSince']`?

Comment: this: `".$_POST['dateSince']."` should be surrounded by `''` like this `'".$_POST['dateSince']."'`

Comment: @CodeBird thank you for saving hours of googling, I really appreciate it, it works perfectly, that's all it was.

Comment: By the way, how do I set the question as answered?

Comment: You can't as I just commented didn't answer, this is not worth being an answer as it is more of typo or something you forgot, just delete the question maybe...

Comment: go on set it as answered, maybe it helps somebody with the same issue

Comment: @PrOjEkTeD btw you should sanitize your variables to protect your code against sql injection, check my updated answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this:

`".$_POST['dateSince']."`

should be surrounded by

`''` like this

`'".$_POST['dateSince']."'`

and you should sanitize your variables to protect yourself against sql injection,
if you're using mysql

```
WHERE Reservation.InDate >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateSince'])."'
AND (Reservation.ResStatus = 'Occupied' OR Reservation.ResStatus = 'Vacant')";
```

if you're using mysqli

```
WHERE Reservation.InDate >= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['dateSince'])."'
AND (Reservation.ResStatus = 'Occupied' OR Reservation.ResStatus = 'Vacant')";
```

Note: better look into mysqli or PDO prepared statements...